# convert the sql statements to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert the below sql statements to stored procedure, which should return me list of delete statements from output parameter.

At present this statement print the sql delete statements on message box of sql server, but i need to make a stored procedure.

The input parameters provide are the table name and the primary key column name and one output parameter which will give the list of sql delete statements.

Can someone help!

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tmp') is not null
    drop table #tmp;
create table  #tmp  (id int, tablename varchar(256), lvl int, ParentTable varchar(256));

insert into #tmp 
exec dbo.usp_SearchFK @table='dbo.M', @debug=0;

declare @where varchar(max) ='where M.id=2' -- if @where clause is null or 
empty, it will delete tables as a whole with the right order
declare @curFK cursor, @fk_object_id int;
declare @sqlcmd varchar(max)='', @crlf char(2)=char(0x0d)+char(0x0a);
declare @child varchar(256), @parent varchar(256), @lvl int, @id int;
declare @i int;
declare @t table (tablename varchar(128));
declare @curT cursor;
if isnull(@where, '')= ''
begin
    set @curT = cursor for select tablename, lvl from #tmp order by lvl desc
    open @curT;
    fetch next from @curT into @child, @lvl;
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin -- loop @curT
        if not exists (select 1 from @t where tablename=@child)
            insert into @t (tablename) values (@child);
        fetch next from @curT into @child, @lvl;
    end -- loop @curT
    close @curT;
    deallocate @curT;

    select  @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd + 'delete from ' + tablename + @crlf from @t ;
    print @sqlcmd;
end
else
begin 
    declare curT cursor for
    select  lvl, id
    from #tmp
    order by lvl desc;

    open curT;
    fetch next from curT into  @lvl, @id;
    while @@FETCH_STATUS =0
    begin
        set @i=0;
        if @lvl =0
        begin -- this is the root level
            select @sqlcmd = 'delete from ' + tablename from #tmp where id = 
        @id;
        end -- this is the roolt level

        while @i < @lvl
        begin -- while

            select top 1 @child=TableName, @parent=ParentTable from #tmp 
        where id <= @id-@i and lvl <= @lvl-@i order by lvl desc, id desc;
            set @curFK = cursor for
            select object_id from sys.foreign_keys 
            where parent_object_id = object_id(@child)
            and referenced_object_id = object_id(@parent)

            open @curFK;
            fetch next from @curFk into @fk_object_id
            while @@fetch_status =0
            begin -- @curFK

                if @i=0
                    set @sqlcmd = 'delete from ' + @child + @crlf +
                    'from ' + @child + @crlf + 'inner join ' + @parent  ;
                else
                    set @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd + @crlf + 'inner join ' + @parent ;

                ;with c as 
                (
                    select child = 
            object_schema_name(fc.parent_object_id)+'.' + 
            object_name(fc.parent_object_id), child_col=c.name
                    , parent = 
            object_schema_name(fc.referenced_object_id)+'.' + 
            object_name(fc.referenced_object_id), parent_col=c2.name
                    , rnk = row_number() over (order by (select null))
                    from sys.foreign_key_columns fc
                    inner join sys.columns c
                    on fc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
                    and fc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
                    inner join sys.columns c2
                    on fc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id
                    and fc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
                    where fc.constraint_object_id=@fk_object_id
                )
                    select @sqlcmd =@sqlcmd +  case rnk when 1 then ' on '  
              else ' and ' end 
                    + @child +'.'+ child_col +'='  +  @parent   +'.' + 
              parent_col
                    from c;
                    fetch next from @curFK into @fk_object_id;
            end --@curFK
            close @curFK;
            deallocate @curFK;
            set @i = @i +1;
        end --while
        print @sqlcmd + @crlf + @where + ';';
        print '';
        fetch next from curT into  @lvl, @id;
    end
    close curT;
    deallocate curT;
end

go
```

Comment: What in the world is this trying to do? Looping (cursors, while loops etc) should be avoided whenever possible. You have them nested 3 or 4 deep. The performance of this would be horrific with any amount of data.

Comment: echo sean...sql is a set based language, not linear and what you are trying to do here is horribly linear, 1 line going through this would likely take a minute let alone 1 million.  Scrap this, go back to what you are trying to accomplish, and try again...post here if you need help.